# Finding the first and the last address for a given IP address

Tags: ip, address

It is small question, but I can't figure out these things.
Please help me in simply way how to do this.

Consider the given ip address is 198.51.100.39/28.
From this how can I found the first ,last and the number of address in this network

Comment: See [How do you calculate the prefix, network, subnet, and host numbers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499). It is simple binary math.

Comment: If you have a linux machine - install ipcalc

$ ipcalc 198.51.100.39/28
Address:   198.51.100.39        11000110.00110011.01100100.0010 0111
Netmask:   255.255.255.240 = 28 11111111.11111111.11111111.1111 0000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.15             00000000.00000000.00000000.0000 1111
=>
Network:   198.51.100.32/28     11000110.00110011.01100100.0010 0000
HostMin:   198.51.100.33        11000110.00110011.01100100.0010 0001
HostMax:   198.51.100.46        11000110.00110011.01100100.0010 1110
Broadcast: 198.51.100.47        11000110.00110011.01100100.0010 1111

Answer (score 0):

The math behind requires converting IPv4 notation and [CIDR block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_blocks) into binary.

```
198.51.100.39    in binary  11000110 00110011 01100100 00100111
255.255.255.240  (for /28)  11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000
---------------------------------------------------------------
FIRST (from logical AND)    11000110 00110011 01100100 00100000
LAST  (host bits => 1)      11000110 00110011 01100100 00101111
```

These converted back into IPv4 notation gives range `198.51.100.32 - 198.51.100.47`.

The number of addresses can be calculated directly from CIDR (`/28`): 2³²⁻²⁸ = 2⁴ = 16.

If you don't want to do this every time, you can use a [CIDR to IPv4 Conversion](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) tool.